# What are the CF built-in webserver attributes?

Tags: coldfusion, attributes, coldfusion-8, jrun

[There are some attributes listed here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/installserver_09.html) for ColdFusion's built-in webserver, like `mapCheck` and `interface`, but I can't find any documentation on what these do.

Does anyone know where there is documentation for these attributes? or what they do?

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion (up to 9) runs on Jrun (and it's a config item for the proxy service your looking at), so I'd start at the Jrun documentation:

http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/jrun/

Comment: I just did a search through those docs and can't find anything on 'mapCheck'

Comment: mapCheck =  "the time how often web server connector should refrehs mappings." http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/javadocs/jrun/servlet/jrpp/JRunProxyService.html